# Alter statement dropped table

Tags: mysql, heidisql

I am using HeidiSQL version 8.1.0 and was improving performance to some queries by playing around with different indexes. Accidently I was adding a field which I quickly removed. Then without saving I was altering my index. The result is that the whole table was dropped. Is anyone able to explain what happened? How is it possible?

In the query history I find:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `foo_database`.`nodes`;

ALTER TABLE `nodes`
    ALTER `parent_id` DROP DEFAULT;

ALTER TABLE `nodes`
    CHANGE COLUMN `parent_id` `parent_id` BINARY(16) NULL AFTER `id`,
    DROP INDEX `rgt`,
    DROP INDEX `lft`,
    ADD INDEX `set` (`lft`, `rgt`) USING BTREE;
/* SQL Error (1025): Error on rename of './foo_database/#sql-43c_31' to './foo_database/nodes' (errno: 150)

Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed */
ALTER TABLE `nodes`
    ALTER `parent_id` DROP DEFAULT;
/* SQL Error (1146): Table 'foo_database.nodes' doesn't exist */
```

Comment: You have **backups**, right?

Comment: Yes, I have. I will try to reproduce my example and see if I can come to a conclusion.